# View Pager page not refreshing?

Tags: android

I have used SlidingTabLayout and Viewpager to make sliding Tab in fragement. And i have implemented it successfully. [image: image with three tab]

My code for adding the fragment under view pager

```
         void setUpFragementPager(View view) {
          List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
          MyFragmentAdapter mPagerAdapter;
         //for each fragment you want to add to the pager
          Bundle page = new Bundle();
          page.putString("url", "d");

          fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), 
          AppFragement.class.getName(), page));

          fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), 
          CatFragement.class.getName(), page));

           fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity()
            ,FavFragement.class.getName(),page));

            //after adding all the fragments write the below lines
            mViewPager=(ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            mPagerAdapter = new
            MyFragmentAdapter(super.getFragmentManager(), fragments);

            mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

            mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) 
           view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

           mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

           if (mParam1.toString().equals("1")){
               mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
               mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
          else
             mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

       }
```

Now when i click on MyLibrary button (Image 2) 
[image: Image 2]under drawer the Tab should change to CATEGORY but what happen is currently now is that , white strip  is going under the category tab but the **CatFragement** is not loading under the same tab(category tab). You can see it in the snapshot (image 3)
[image: Image 3]

I used 
           mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
           mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
but it leading me to the my desired result . The Desired Result should be look like image4 which you can see in the snapshot too.
[image: Image 4]

Please help me where i am doing wrong.